# Magento SortBy options not available in other category

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting

I am facing issue with sort-by option.I have two categories in that one of category(Products list page) should not display some attributes in sort-by option.

Like this:

> In First category: Array ( [position] => Position [name] => Name )
>
> In Second category: Array ( [position] => Position [name] => Name [price] => Price [sponsored] => Sponsored [paidmembers] => Paid

Two attributes is missed in First Category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check below setting shown in image

login `admin panel`

1) go to `catalog->manage Categories`

2) select your category.

3) click on `Display setting`

4) and check `Avliable listing sory by` option and select sort by options that you want

[image]